# When I try to run this BIRT report the program shows me this message **missing ; before statement (<inline>#1)** and don't have any statement there

Tags: java, exception, birt

I don't hace any statement in the script section and the message appears there.

If I try to see the Script section it appears locked and I cannot edit anything. I wanted to see in that section because the message.

[image: Locked the script section]

When I try to see the preview it shows me this error
[image]

This is the log

```
org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing ; before statement (<inline>#1)
at org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.runtimeError(DefaultErrorReporter.java:77)
at org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.error(DefaultErrorReporter.java:64)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:188)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:166)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:223)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:210)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:203)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.autoInsertSemicolon(Parser.java:1067)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:1044)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statement(Parser.java:901)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:540)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:478)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2348)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1335)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1324)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.javascript.JavascriptEngine$3.run(JavascriptEngine.java:240)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.javascript.JavascriptEngine$3.run(JavascriptEngine.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.javascript.JavascriptEngine.compile(JavascriptEngine.java:236)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.javascript.JavascriptEngine.compile(JavascriptEngine.java:1)
at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.ScriptContext.compile(ScriptContext.java:153)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.compile(ExecutionContext.java:779)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.evaluate(ExecutionContext.java:713)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.evaluateExpression(EngineTask.java:1284)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.evaluateDefaultValue(EngineTask.java:1249)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask$2.visitScalarParameter(EngineTask.java:1625)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask$ParameterVisitor.visit(EngineTask.java:1540)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask$ParameterVisitor.visit(EngineTask.java:1504)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.usingParameterValues(EngineTask.java:1721)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.doRun(DatasetPreviewTask.java:298)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.runDataset(DatasetPreviewTask.java:278)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.execute(DatasetPreviewTask.java:89)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.DataSetPreviewer.preview(DataSetPreviewer.java:68)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.ResultSetPreviewPage$5.run(ResultSetPreviewPage.java:372)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
```

Comment: looks like you don't have selected the data set before selecting the script tab.

Comment: When I had the problem, i saw that it has data

Answer (score 0):

For solving this I created a new empty report and copy and paste all of the configuration from the old report to the new one and worked.

I don't know if this is the best solution but for me it worked.

Comment: If you put your rptdesign, rptlibrary and js files under version control (e.g. with SVN), you could compare the failing version with the last one that was working. Probably the error was not in a *script* (such as initialize or a DS afterOpen), but in an *expression* (such as the visibility expression or the expression of a dynamic text item).